# QR Code generator only generate the QR code for the first input

Tags: javascript, html, qr-code

I am new to stackoverflow and i wanted to create a QR code generator that translate the 2 inputs into a QR code, however the code only translate the first input into a QR code and does not include the information for the second input.
I also try using querySelectorAll but it doesnt change anything I hope good sirs would be so kind to teach me where I'm wrong at.

here is the code for HTML

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PracticeQRProgram</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h1>QR CODE GENERATOR</h1>
        </header>
          <div class="form">
              <input class="form" type="text" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Enter Full Name">
              <input class="form" type="text" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Enter ID no.">
            <button>Submit</button>
          </div>
          
        <div class="qr-code">
          <img src="" alt="qr-code">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the code for javascript

```
var wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper"),
qrInput = wrapper.querySelector(".form input");
generateBtn = wrapper.querySelector(".form button");
qrImg = wrapper.querySelector(".qr-code img");
let preValue;
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let qrValue = qrInput.value.trim();
    if(!qrValue || preValue === qrValue) return;
    preValue = qrValue;
    generateBtn.innerText = "Submitting...";
    qrImg.src = `https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=200x200&data=${qrValue}`;
    qrImg.addEventListener("load", () => {
        wrapper.classList.add("active");
        generateBtn.innerText = "QR Code";
    });
});
qrInput.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
    if(!qrInput.value.trim()) {
        wrapper.classList.remove("active");
        preValue = "";
    }
});
```

and here is for the style.css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 10px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url("ICpEP.jpg");
  background-color: #cccccc;
  justify-content: center;
}
.wrapper{
  height: 650px;
  max-width: 410px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 20px 25px 0;
  transition: height 0.2s ease;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.wrapper.active{
  height: 650px;
}
header h1{
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
header p{
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: #575757;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.wrapper .form{
  margin: 20px 0 25px;
}
.form :where(input, button){
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.1s ease;
}
.form input{
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0 17px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
.form input :focus{
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
}
.form input::placeholder{
  color: #999;
}
 .form button{
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  background: #3498DB;
}
.qr-code{
  opacity: 0;
  display: flex;
  padding: 33px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  align-items: center;
  pointer-events: none;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.wrapper.active .qr-code{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.05s ease;
}
.qr-code img{
  width: 170px;
}
@media (max-width: 430px){
  .wrapper{
    height: 650px;
    padding: 16px 20px;
  }
  .wrapper.active{
    height: 650px;
  }
  header p{
    color: #696969;
  }
  .form :where(input, button){
    height: 52px;
  }
  .qr-code img{
    width: 160px;
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
qrImg.src = `https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=200x200&data=${qrValue}`;
```

You are only sending the `qrValue` to the api.  You will have to read and send both the id and name info to the api if you want both encoded.

That being said I would adjust the code a bit to make it easier to reason about.

Firstly I would add unique id's to each of the input elements eg:

```
<input id="name-input" class="form" type="text" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Enter Full Name">
<input id="id-input" class="form" type="text" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Enter ID no.">
```

Next I would select these elements directly using:

```
var qrNameInput = document.getElementById("name-input");
var qrIdInput = document.getElementById("id-input");
```

Then in your event listener I would read these values:

```
var name = qrNameInput.value.trim();
var id = qrIdInput.value.trim();
```

And finally send both of these information on to the api:

```
qrImg.src = `https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=200x200&data="name:${name},id:${id}"`;
```

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll()` is the way to do this !

but you have to change some of your code, because it returns a NodeList, so you'll have to iterate on the result to find your values, like this :

```js
const qrInputs = wrapper.querySelectorAll('.form input');

generateBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let qrValue = getQrValue();
  //[...]
}

function getQrValue() {
  //To use array function, you have to cast the NodeList to an Array
  const inputsArray = Array.from(qrInputs)
  //getting an array of values from inputs
  const values = inputsArray.map((input) => input.value);
  // return a signle string with all values separated with '_'
  return values.join('_');
}
```

And with `qrInput.addEventListener("keyup", [...])` you can just set the listener on the form instead ([events are bubbling up](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing))

Comment: Yes! you where right (T^T)
i did try querySelectorAll but did not include getQrValue and function. Thank you good sir